# What account permissions are necessary for a powershell script to have access to get-gporeport?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, gpo

I've written a powershell script to be run periodically to query particular GPO's, record them, and check them against a predefined configuration, monitoring for unauthorized changes.

I then created a windows task scheduler task to run the script, and run it as a service account created for this purpose.  When the account is set as local admin, the script works fine.  When the local admin role is removed, the script does not populate the .xml files with the GPO content.

I tested whether the account has rights to write to those files by having them write to them with a simple " add-content $filepath "foo" " and it worked, so the rights issue doesn't appear to stem from whether the account is allowed to write to those files.  It seems that the issue is whether the account is allowed to use the get-gporeport cmdlet.

Can anyone suggest what might be going on here?  Or how to fix it?

Comment: Try adding some exception handling and logging to your script. You should be able to figure out the problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I've implemented this suggestion - this is the error message:
14-Mar-2014 17:00:00 (00:00:00) - Attempting to export fooPolicy
14-Mar-2014 17:00:07 (00:00:07) - Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object